# Is there a workaround for SVG <animateTransform> not working on safari for Iphone?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

animateTransform is not working properly for me on safari (both Iphone and windows safari 5).  Here is the fiddle.  Compare it in Chrome vs Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/20wzj8fk/1/

This is undoubtedly a bug, but what I'm hoping is that someone has had this same problem and found a workaround.  Neither google nor SO has turned up this exact same issue for me.  Here is the code:

```
<svg id="thesvg">
<defs>

<path id="Xprototype"  d="M -20,-20 L20,20 M20,-20 L -20,20"  stroke="blue"/>
                    </defs>
<g class="myelement" fill="transparent" elementnum="1" transform="translate(20 120)">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#Xprototype"></use>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="xml" type="translate" to="20 120" dur="1s" begin="0"  ></animateTransform>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="xml" type="translate" to="140 140" dur="1s" begin="1" fill="freeze"></animateTransform>
    </g>

    </svg>
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI: SMIL animation has only partial support in Safari 5.1.  See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil (click the "Show all" button to see v5.1.